# Validation.ErrorEvent behavior difference when constructor injecting vs static binding of data context

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

**Overview**

I have two views, one contained inside the other via a ContentControl declaration. The view model for the containing view gets its view model injected via its constructor and sets the DataContext there. The lower, contained view gets its DataContext through XAML declaration, using a view model locator class. We use a custom ValidationHelper class that hooks into the Validation.ErrorEvent handler in order to support contained views being able to notify their parent views about any data validation errors.

However, there is a difference in behavior that I don't understand. When using this method of statically binding the DataContext in the lower view's XAML, the Error handler activates for the lower, contained view once, then both controls get loaded. But, if I switch the lower view to use constructor injection for its view model and set the DataContext in the constructor, then the same Error handler invokes for both parent and child views before they're both loaded.

**Code**

XAML code for upper view

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUpperView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- OTHER CONTROLS ARE HERE -->
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=MyLowerViewInstance, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

XAML.cs code for upper view

```
public partial class MyUpperView : UserControl
{
    public MyUpperView(MyUpperViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

ViewModel code for upper view

```
public class MyUpperViewModel
{
    private object _sourceObjectUI;

    public object MyLowerViewInstance
    {
        get { return _sourceObjectUI; }
    }

    public MyUpperViewModel()
    {
        _sourceObjectUI = new MySourceObjectUI();
    }
}
```

XAML code for lower view

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyLowerView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:myns="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyAssembly" >

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <myns:MyViewModelLocator x:Key="MyVML" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <Binding Mode="OneWay"
                 Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyVML}"
                 Path="MyLowerViewModelProperty" />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyText, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

</UserControl>
```

XAML.cs code for lower view model (this is the default, I'm just including it for reference)

```
public partial class MyLowerView : UserControl
{
    public MyLowerView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

ViewModel code for lower view

```
public class MyLowerViewModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string MyText { get; set; }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        switch(columnName)
        {
            case "MyText":
            {
                // Perform some validation stuff here. If the data doesn't pass validation, set the result string to something other than string.Empty
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, the code works. When the view is created, the MyText property is immediately evaluated for any data errors and raises the Error event on the Validation like normal, which the custom ErrorChangedHandler we have responds to appropriately.

When I remove the lower view's UserControl.DataContext declaration, and instead make the MyLowerViewModel get injected to the XAML.cs constructor, then all of a sudden the ErrorChangedHandler even gets fired twice, once for the lower view, and once for the upper view, even though the TextBox generating the event is only referenced by the lower view.

**I do not understand this difference of behavior.** How can the upper view be raising an event for a control that it doesn't really know about, and only if I constructor inject the data context for the lower view?? Thanks for any help!